# Device orientation using storyboard and uitableview problems

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I am using Xcode 4.3.3 and storyboards i have a UITableView but when the device orientation changes from portrait to landscape the spacing is all messed up i also do not have a .h or .m file for my tableview because the cells are static any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the struts and strings of your cell, label, etc in the size inspector of the utility navigator (Select what you want to modify and press Command-Option-5). In the box labeled Autosizing, select and deselect the connectors and arrows to make the item show up in the correct way. The Example box on the right shows you what the item will look like when your orientation changes.